# How to access an element inside the iframe in aferShow event?

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using Fancybox 2.1.4. I would like to access the element inside the iframe in the afterShow event.

```
        $('.fancybox').fancybox({
            type: 'iframe',
            afterShow: function() {

                 //need to access element #mydiv

            }
            iframe: {
                preload: true 
            }
        });
```

How can I do that? Does preload: true and preload: false has any effect on accessing the element? Suppose that the parent window and the iframe access the pages on the same website.

Comment: Of course it matters. If you disable preloading, then this callback will be fired after iframe is shown while content is still loading. Sorry, I do not remember for v2, but this is how you can access iframe using v3  - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwdBdx?editors=1010

Comment: Janis, thanks for the info! Are you aware of any v2 callbacks in Fancybox v2 that is fired AFTER the content in iframe is loaded? I looked everywhere and was unable to find one.

Comment: I guess you can bind that event by yourself :)

Comment: I am not sure how to do it and make it as a callback for Fancybox 2. Mind showing me an example? If you can put all your comments in an aswer post, I will select it as the asnwer. Best.

Comment: I'm curious, why don't you upgrade to v3?

Comment: I already used v2 heavily in my web app, and it touches so many places. Upgrading to v3 is not an option at this moment. I also briefly tested v3, and I was not able to find any callbacks that is called AFTER the content in iframe is loaded when `preload: false`

Comment: If you can not find, then you can create one! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can access iframe and, for example, bind custom load event if using v3:

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
  iframe : {
    preload: false
  },
  afterLoad : function(instance, slide) {
    slide.$slide.find('iframe').on('load', function() {
      alert('done');
    });
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXwoNM?editors=1010